# JAX-RS 2.0 - How to get entity from Response object

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, dropwizard

I'm using JAX-RS 2.0 with Dropwizard 0.8.0-rc1 and I really can't figure out how to pull my entity from `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` object. `response.getEntity()` gives me `ByteArrayOutputStream`. I can create two requests - one that gives me headers and links and the other that gives me my response entity, but it seems like a stupid, wasteful and unclear thing to do. Is there a way for getting entity from response object?

My current test code is as follows:

```
public class GroupsResourceTest {

    public static String CONFIGURATION_FILE = "src/test/resources/test-conf.yml";

    @ClassRule
    public final static DropwizardAppRule<BpmConsoleConfiguration> RULE =
            new DropwizardAppRule<>(BpmConsoleApplication.class, CONFIGURATION_FILE);

    static Client client;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initClient(){
        client = new JerseyClientBuilder(RULE.getEnvironment()).build("client");
        client.register(HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(User.ADMIN.login, User.ADMIN.password));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldGetGroups() {
        //when
        WebTarget resource = target("/groups");
        List<String> groups = resource.request().get(new GenericType<>(List.class)); //first request
        Response response = resource.request().get(); //second request
        Link self = response.getLink("self");
        //then
        assertThat(self.getUri().getPath()).isEqualTo("/groups");
        assertThat(groups).contains(User.ADMIN.login);

    }

    public WebTarget target(String path){
        String url = String.format("http://localhost:%d%s", RULE.getLocalPort(), path);
        return client.target(url);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

- [`public abstract <T> T readEntity(Class<T> entityType)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity%28java.lang.Class%29) - Read the message entity input stream as an instance of specified Java type using a MessageBodyReader that supports mapping the message entity stream onto the requested type.

Comment: What are use cases, I mean. When one should getEntity and readEntity?

Comment: @CroskCool getEntity on outbound Response, readEntity on inbound Response